# HTML iframe containing referral link

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a problem when I use my referral link (For Earning Sites) inside the "iframe" tag of HTML , The problem is not with the site , but in the referrals link
I used that way to build NEXT - PREVIEWS - HTML document with js code , SO I try the example below , but that's not work , Also the direct iframe source not work ,
How can I solve that ?
This is my HTML code ..

```
<div id="frame-div" style="clear:right;position:relative;margin:auto auto;width:auto;height:auto;">
         <iframe id="frame" src="" style="margin-top:10px;width:800px;height:570px;float:none;position:relative;">
          <p>NO FRAME</p>
          </iframe>
```

And My Js Code is very simple..

```
function changeframe(){
document.getElementById('frame').src = "http://YYYYYY.COM/?r=XXX";
}
```

I use the inspect tools and call the "changeframe" function , It called successfully , but the problem is stilled not taking the refferal "XXX" HERE ! I check that from my refferals by contacting them !
I used many codes (setAttribute ,  jquery ..) But I still have the problem with ALL SITES , Can help please ? thanks.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question to explain *exactly* what the problem is with your code?  You say `the problem is stilled not taking the referral "XXX" HERE !`  What does that sentence mean?  Do you mean that the content from YYYYYY.com appears but the people at that site claim they're not seeing your referral?  Or that the content from the site does not appear at all?  Please give as much detail as possible when posting a question.

Comment: yes I say It Called successfully , I was meaning that the site is loaded and appears. yes as you say people not seeing my referral link when claim , also the referral link not processed by the site (ALL sites) , Also when I copy and open the link in the browser , It's work perfectly , Why that happened in  `iframe` tag , I dont know !

Comment: Are you sure that the src URL doesn't need any encoding? I'm not sure, but browsers might encode the pasted URL before actually going with it.

Comment: I dont think that , when I paste the link `site.com/?r=REF_Link` in the browser , it takes it and return url only `site.com/index.php` after the process , but in frame not take it , also I check the frame source opened and the link is fully created in the frame ! So where is the problem ?

Comment: Don't know... any errors on console?

Comment: NO , the iframe is shown , but the problem that it's not take the ref. link !

Comment: We can't help much. In a last attempt, I'd suggest you to consider (in an analog way) the information shown here: http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#faq-referer

Comment: try that in Jsbin (http://jsbin.com) , It worked and counted me one referral for one time , because Of the site server IP.
And I want to NOTE that My Referrals Claim not me , I contact 4 of them and It's work great in their browser , But I'm not receiving referrals !
I'm also not beginner in Developing , But This is the first time that I faced Like This Problem.
Can Help with other suggestion , and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly It's Work I dont know Where the problem was , But I'm using now $('frame') accessing with jquery but I add the link and ref link into one variable then changing it , and Maybe if anyone have the same problem , this could be helped.
Anyway , Thanks to EveryOne Who Helped me.